# Right shift key stays activated after press, nearby keys (/ and ') release it

Tags: keyboard

Without any known obvious cause (eg. spillage, dirt), the right shift key on my 2021 apple silicon macbook running latest Sonoma has started misbehaving. When it's pressed, it stays pressed - in sticky keys fashion - until either the /, ' or backspace buttons are pressed.

It could well be a hardware problem, but I'm not convinced of it. It sounds a lot like [this old thread on the apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252575304?sortBy=best). One of the suggested solutions there is to enable/disable the sticky keys functionality, but for me that option is greyed out..
[image]

Is it normal that sticky keys would be disabled here? Does anyone have another suggestion how to fix the key?

Comment: Rule out the keyboard by trying with a cheap USB keyboard.  Does the problem persist?

Comment: Thanks @Allan. I tried with a bluetooth keyboard, and the shift key behaves normally. Do you think this proves it's a hardware problem with the keyboard?

Comment: It does two things:  rules out software and/or a setting that could be causing it plus it definitely points you in the direction of a hardware failure.